# How to map localhost:port from bokeh server to remote public_html website?

Tags: python, html, localhost, bokeh

I have some interactive plots using bokeh and I can run the sever to visualise it with my browser using:

```
bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

This will run the server and show my plots on

```
http://localhost:5006/myapp
```

Now, I work for a university, and I have a public_html directory on a remote computer, which I can use to develop a website.

My question is, how do I map or point to the bokeh server from my public_html/index.html file such that it has a public address like:

```
http://example.uni/myapp
```

Or even embed it on my index.html using iframe

Comment: Not a programming question. And you are going to need more than a web folder for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need a proper webserver i.e. nginx for that. And then a server that runs the python code  (bokeh - server).

Alternatively you can use the bokeh components function to create static html and js files which you can embed in your static html and serve it from your html directory. Static plots are still interactive (zoom, and other tools)since the data is included in the js files. But the logic on the server does not run in the static files for sure.

[See Bokeh Documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#html-files)